# how to point AWS Route53 subdomain to AWS Lightsail instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53, amazon-lightsail

I have setup a Wordpress on Lightsail, and have created a static IP which I can access WP ok.

I have migrated my `.co.uk` domain across to Route53 from another provider and am trying to point `blog.example.co.uk` to my Lightsail instance.

In Lightsail I have setup a DNS record like this:

```
A   example.co.uk           12.34.56.78
A   blog.example.co.uk      12.34.56.78
```

It then lists these DNS servers in Lightsail:

```
ns-849.awsdns-42.net
ns-1643.awsdns-13.co.uk
ns-341.awsdns-42.com
ns-1516.awsdns-61.org
```

I've taken those DNS servers and set on the root of my domain in Route 53 under `Domains > Registered Domains`

I am not sure if that was the correct thing to do, as I will have other subdomains eventually that will point elsewhere, **should the Lightsail DNS servers be added at that level? If not, what do I set them back to be?**

I have also created a Route53 Hosted Zone, and have created an "A" entry that links blog.example.co.uk to 12.34.56.78, is that required?

Comment: Currently trying to achieve the same. I believe you can't set the NS entries on the root domain to the Lightsail DNS servers': the registered domain's NS entries (under Route53 > Registered Domains > Domain, upper right corner) must match the one on the hosted zone, or Lightsail's DNS servers.

Comment: I'm trying to create a new NS record for my subdomain, and setting those NS entries to my Lightsail instance's, and then adding an alias record (A) that points to my static IP – but hasn't worked yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, I was facing the same challenge.

What ended up working for me was simply creating an Alias Record (`A`) for my subdomain, `subdomain.example.com`, that points to the static IP of my Lightsail instance.

I **did not** add Lightsail's DNS servers anywhere on Route53.

I made sure that the `NS` entries for my root domain – `example.com` – pointed to the *Name servers* entries on my registered domain in Route53.

You can find the name servers associated with your Route53 registered domain by going to `Registered domains > mydomain.com`; they're located on the upper-right corner.

Comment: Yep, that worked for me, thanks. The only slight difference is that I deleted and re-created the hosted zone, as suggested here: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=236377